# How can I find SERVERNAME and SHARENAME from domain name

Tags: windows, network-shares, domain

I have an FQDN reference to a Windows server. `\\aserver.my.com\stuff`

It can also be referred to by IP address. `\\192.168.1.33\stuff`

How can I find the Windows SERVERNAME and SHARENAME?

The following does not appear to work.

```
M:>dir \\ASERVER\STUFF
The network path was not found.
```

Comment: well, the host name is the first segment of the FQDN, and the share name is after the third `\`. Not sure why you are asking, since this seems obvious. please expound on where you are having trouble.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I have edited the question to include an example of what I believe you are saying. Please tell me what I misunderstood.

Comment: does it change if you use `\\aserver,ny.com\stuff` ? if so that indicates that your system is not handling dns domain appendation correctly.

Comment: Sometimes if you have multiple domains the DNS configs may be this way be design rather than not handling correctly too (ask your network admins) for security reasons so append the domain name [FQDN] after the server name as Frank suggest and see if that resolves `\\aserver.ny.com\stuff`. It may or may not be for some security reason, etc. based on your company policies and network configuration.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Using `dir \\aserver,my.com\stuff` yields `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: sorry, replace the comma with a period. I noticed it after the 5-minute window for editing comments elapsed.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I've already said in the question that I can refer to the share through a domain reference.

Comment: Are those real names or just example references? Is it a work domain environment? It could be that the share is a DFS share so it does not have to be on that server. Have you admin credentials for 192.168.1.33? If yes you can check on the server. If the short name does not work it could be that WINS is disabled, that your computer DNS suffix settings are not right. Does `ping aserver` return an IP? You have to give us more details about the setup of the environment. You could map the fqdn to a letter and then dir the letter.

Comment: Example names. Corporate work environment. I am not admin. Both ping and nslookup work for "aserver". I already have a drive letter mapped to the FQDN. Using `DIR` shows the directory contents. I do not see anything about the SERVERNAME or SHARENAME.